# Error when trying to clone darknet on kaggle notebook . Help anyone?

Tags: github, kaggle, darknet

code --> `!git clone http://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/`

message -->
Cloning into 'darknet'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/': Could not resolve host: github.com

I tried with this code -->
`!git clone http://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git`
but still giving the same error message.Is there any syntax error?

Comment: ```git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't turned on internet on kaggle notebook. My bad..